# Python use loop for csv list

Tags: python, csv

I need help going through this problem

I use python 2.7

cat r0_v4-aver.csv

> 134323

cat u3_v4-aver.csv

> 127757

cat u3_v4-aver.csv

> 153126

```
f_r0v4 = "/home/ubuntu/script/prtg/report-wyze/csv/r0_v4-aver.csv"
f_u3v4 = "/home/ubuntu/script/prtg/report-wyze/csv/u3_v4-aver.csv"
f_t1v4 = "/home/ubuntu/script/prtg/report-wyze/csv/t1_v4-aver.csv"
f_g1_v4 =  [ f_r0v4,f_u3v4,f_t1v4 ]
f_g1all_v4 = "/home/ubuntu/script/prtg/report-wyze/csv/g1_all_v4.csv"
o_g1_all_v4 = csv.writer(open(f_g1all_v4, 'wb' ))

for k_g1_v4 in f_g1_v4:
    o_g1_v4 = csv.reader(open(k_g1_v4, 'rb'))
    t_g1_v4 = o_g1_v4.next()
    o_g1_all_v4.writerow(t_g1_v4)
```

---

output

I need show is 135285,127362,15540

not show
134323
127757
153126

thanks

Comment: Posted code does not run ('o_g1_all_v4` undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: just replace

```
o_g1_all_v4.writerow(t_g1_v4)
```

with

```
o_g1_all_v4.write(t_g1_v4 + ",")
```

Note: You need to to create `o_g1_all_v4` file without csv module , like :

```
o_g1_all_v4 = open(<filename.csv>,"w">)
```

and then use the `write` method on it.

Comment: _is not work_  </br>
"./test-note.py", line 30, in 
  </br>
`o_g1_all_v4.write(t_g1_v4 + ",") `

Comment: Updated my answer , please have a look, Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: ['134323'],['127757'],['153126'],